# Hierarchy of fixed clipped elements

Tags: css, z-index, hierarchy, fixed, clip-path

I have two objects with `position: fixed;`

The first is placed right after the `<body>` tag the second inside a div.

I want the red one (the one inside the div) to be in front of the black one but it needs to be clipped in that containing div.

It's working fine with `z-index` etc but as soon as i apply the `clip-path` to the containing div the red square is placed under the black one.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.b1 {
  background: #3D6CB9;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.b2 {
  background: #21ABA5;
  height: 160vh;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  left: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
}

.t1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.t2 {
  z-index: 2;
  background: crimson;
  transform: translateY(20px) translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="top t1"></div>

<div class="box b1">
  <div class="top t2"></div>
</div>
<div class="box b2"></div>
```

Comment: i guess clip-path create a new containing block

Comment: @TemaniAfif is there any other way to clip it to the div without clip-path?

Comment: yes but how you want to clip it ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this because as soon as you add a clipping path, you bring the element into the stacking context which means you want the parent (b1) to be behind the black but the child to be infront of it (t2) and that cannot be achieved